# Ubuntu 16.04 + DVD = Crash

Tags: nvidia, sound, 16.04, video, dvd

I'm a new Ubuntu user.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried playing a DVD on VLC (which worked perfectly fine with Ubuntu 14.04). After about a minute, the video stops, while the sound continues. If I'm lucky, VLC will crash the computer while I try to stop it from continuing. So far I've been very lucky.

For some details:

I've installed libdvdcss2 and Ubuntu restricted extras.

The computer: AMD FX 8350 CPU @4GHz; 16 GB RAM; Brand-spaking new LG DVD drive (just over 6 months); 2 TB HDD; nVidia Geforce 960

So I've installed the appropriate software, and I know it's not a hardware issue.

I read on another forum to set VLC to play DVD video as OpenGL, so I tried that, and it didn't work.

I've removed the restricted extras and am still experiencing the problem.

Kicking back to 14.04 is "technically" an option, though not entertaining.

I'll take a moment here to ask for instructions for how to create a log of events when a program freezes to the point it crashes the system and I have to press the reset switch to reboot the machine.

I'm also wondering - could this be something that needs to be ironed out with Ubuntu 16 (did I find a bug)?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Pre-edit I'd love to provide output, but the message apparently thought it was spam.

So, to recap.

- I install Ubuntu 16.04
- I install libdvdcss2
- DVD playback works.
- I install Ubuntu restricted extras.
- DVD playback stops working.
- I **remove** Ubuntu restricted extras.
- DVD playback still doesn't work.

So, any ideas?  Should I just reinstall 16.04?  Or go back to 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED  => After disabling GPU support in VLC, everything was working fine

I have to confirm this behaviour without DVD!
I just installed Ubuntu LTS 16.04 and the VLC Player with no any extras. During playing an mp4 file (copied to the filesystem) the system freezes without any chance to check why. No remote login with ssh possible. Only power off and on is possible, just like on windows blue screen.
I am desperately disappointed, I know such crashes only from windows until now.

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) pro Kern:    2
Kern(e) pro Socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA-Knoten:           1
Anbieterkennung:       GenuineIntel
Prozessorfamilie:      6
Modell:                30
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         870  @ 2.93GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1199.000
CPU max MHz:           3066.0000
CPU min MHz:           1199.0000
BogoMIPS:              5851.83
Virtualisierung:       VT-x
L1d Cache:             32K
L1i Cache:             32K
L2 Cache:              256K
L3 Cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you.  I tried your solution, and the DVD I've been using as a test plays now.  The only thing is now is that playback doesn't seem to be as smooth as what it could be.  The video plays, then hangs for just a split second, then continues.  It's not horrible, not actually skipping, but it's just barely noticeable.

**Edit** wasn't done typing.

I haven't tried playing mp4 files (they always worked perfectly); do you have any ideas of how to improve DVD playback so it doesn't seem to hang?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try SMPLAYER, it works good with DVD. Install latest mplayer from https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mplayer-test and then latest SMPLAYER from https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/ubuntu/smplayer select VDPAU under options to enable h/w acceleration.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)